# What is the solution to $x! = i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, factorial, transcendental-numbers

I wanted to know what $x$ is in this equation: **$x! = i$**.

I tried using normal calculators which just gave a math error, tried searching google which was pretty useless, zero results, and last but not least tried using Wolfram, which gave an answer

(which gave 1 answer on pc but gave 3 on an Android device???)

but wolfram's answer provided a transcendental number(the answer) without giving its fractional form, so my questions are

*Note $i$ here is the imaginary unit not a variable*

**What is $x! = i$ in fractional form; How did you get the answer?**

Comment: How do you define $x!$? Also is $i$ the imaginary unit?

Comment: You need the gamma-function to extend the factorial. Then, you can try to solve $$\Gamma(x+1)=i$$

Comment: I would expect Wolfram Alpha to give [several complex solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+Gamma(1%2Bx)%3Di) and for there to be an infinite number.  But sometimes [it only offers one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x!+%3D+i) -  A Wolfram Alpha issue rather than a mathematical issue

Comment: Near $$-0.875-0.685i$$ should be one of the solutions

Comment: @Henry but it usually uses "Alternate form" to write any transcendental number as a fraction. (e.i. asking wolfram  $i^i$ would give 0.2078795... then a section called "Alternate form" which gives $e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}}$)

Comment: @Peter the question clearly asked for it in fractional form, written in bold

Answer (score 3):

The usual notation of $x!$ only covers real numbers. We extend it using the Gamma Function defined as:
$$\Gamma(z)=(z-1)! \text{ for $z\in\Bbb Z^+$}$$
$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^{\infty}{t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt} \text{ otherwise}$$

You'll need to use the second definition to find the answer to your problem, specifically find $$\Gamma(x+1)=i$$

Therefore we are solving:
$$\int_0^{\infty}{t^xe^{-t}dt}=i$$

Comment: that shows how to solve it which is quite appreciated but doesn't exactly tell the answer in its fraction form.

Comment: @MohannadEl-Nesr, I know, because I'm simply guiding you to the answer - it's your task to find it.